# How to delete all photos in the camera roll in iOS 8.x?

Tags: iphone, photos, camera-roll

I have started using auto backup using OneDrive and it works like a charm.  The only problem is that the pictures are left on the phone after being backed up.

Is it possible to empty the camera roll or in some way mass delete photos?  (Even with an app)

Edit:  I stopped using OneDrive because it kept losing pictures.  Switched to Google Photos and it seems to work correctly.

Edit:  And now Google Photos as a button:  "Free up storage" which deletes all the photos that have been backed up.

Comment: do you have ios 8.1 ?

Comment: Yes 8.1.  Meant 8.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Mac, connect your iPhone to it.

There is a build in app (from Apple) called [Image Capture](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH17894) in your Applications folder.

Use it to bulk delete Photos on iPhone.

Comment: doesn't work - "delete" greyed out for iphone photos

Comment: Yeah least with Yosemite there doesn't seem to be any option to delete.  Even tried dragging this to the trash and nothing happened.  I already imported the photos using the new Photos app with no option to delete after import.  This lack of feature support is surprising.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Image Capture... However, if you see a cloud next to the name of your device  then you need to disable iCloud Photo Library before the delete all button will appear.

iPhone:
Settings -> Photos & Camera -> iCloud Photo Library off
Settings -> Photos & Camera -> My Photo Stream off

Then, try Image Capture again and the delete all button will appear.